# Android gradle build: Share library between parent and child

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

We have a project structure like this:

```
Project
|__build.gradle
|__settings.gradle
|__app (android application)
   |__build.gradle
   |__libA (android library)
   |__libB (android library)
      |__libA (android library)
```

My app depends on `libA` and `libB`. `libB` however depends on `libA` again. How should i structure my build so that `app` and `libB` shares the same copy of `libA`?

Note: `app`, `libA` and `libB` are compiled from source and not just jar files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
Project
|__build.gradle
|__settings.gradle
|__app (android application)
   |__build.gradle
|__libA (android library)
   |__build.gradle
|__libB (android library)
   |__build.gradle
```

In `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app' , ':libA' , 'libB'
```

In `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libA')
    compile project(':libB')
}
```

In `libB/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libA')
}
```

Comment: Yeah. This method is working for now. But it compiles libA twice. libA takes some time to compile and more and more libs like libB will depend on it in future.

Comment: @ChiragJain Gradle manages it. 
The other solution is to publish the libA and libB in a maven repository.

Comment: I think gradle is not handing this. I do see double compilation logs for libA. publishing on maven is not an option really. we want to build it from source.

Comment: @ChiragJain double compilation or double log? Gradle uses the cache.

Comment: In settings.gradle i give projectPath and it works like this:

`project(':libA').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../libA')`. Can i give multiple paths like this for the same lib. I want it to look one step higher if not found in current folder.